# « Dont » avec les verbes qui n'ont pas de « de »

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs

Normalement on utilise *dont* avec les verbes qui ont besoin d‘un *de*.

> Pierre est le professeur dont il parlait. (parler de qn)
>       Mes parents ont emprunté l'argent dont ils avaient besoin. (avoir besoin de qc/qn)

Je sais qu'on doit dire:

> Il est sorti avec la fille dont tu connais la sœur. (Connaître qn)

mais pourquoi? Je n'ai pas trouvé de règle qui explique cet usage....

Comment: Le pronom relatif *dont* s'utilise dans de nombreux cas dont je ne me souviens pas. En règle générale, il débute une proposition relative à l'intérieur de laquelle il joue le rôle d'un complément prépositionnel. Dans le votre, il sert à représenter le nom qui le précède, ici *la fille*. L'équivalent du verbe avec *de* serait ici, en reprenant votre typo  (Commanitre la soeur de). J'ai peur qu'il n'y ait pas d'équivalent anglais... "... the girl you know the sister." ?

Comment: To the extent that finding an English equivalent would help, there's "The girl whose sister you [happen to] know," where the "whose" marks a  connection {possession] with the subject (the girl) and not with the verb (to know). Using the passive voice helps me see this better in French by getting "la soeur" right behind "dont" (although I doubt if it's correct): "...la fille dont la soeur t'est connue."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La pronom **dont** est utilisé ici au lieu de **que** car il remplace un antécédent précédé par **de**.

> Tu connais la sœur ***de*** la fille.

donne :

> La fille **dont** tu connais la sœur

En anglais, ç'aurait pu être :

> the girl **whose** sister you know

soit :

> the girl you know the sister **of**.

Sans ce **de**, on n'aurait pas utilisé **dont** :

> Tu connais *la fille*.

donne :

> Il est sorti avec la fille **que** tu connais.

Il aurait donc fallu écrire

> Il est sorti avec la fille dont tu connais la sœur. (Connaître la sœur **de** qn)